# Layout issue in Linearlayout with small resolution device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

hello friends i want to make layout linear layout see for more information click on High resolution image at below

So i create layout file like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_rca_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:background="@color/colorThemeGreen"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_rca_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel_child_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rel_left1"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_gray_bg_left_corner"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/counter_rca_accepted_ticket"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/label_rca_accepted_ticket"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/counter_rca_accepted_ticket"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                        android:text="Accepted Tickets"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="8dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label_rca_user"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_parts_main"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/support"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_30dp"

                    android:text="REMOTE CALL ASSISTANCE"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rel_righ1"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_gray_bg_right_corner"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/counter_rca_pending_ticket"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/label_rca_pending_ticket"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/counter_rca_pending_ticket"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Accepted Tickets"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="8dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

When i run above code i get small resolution device output like this

[Small resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucej0.png)

and i get high resolution device output like this

[High Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5QPj.png)

Any idea how can i solve small resolution device output? your all suggestions are appriciable

Comment: Are you using alternative drawables?

Comment: @vidulaJ: Alternat drawable menas for what?

Comment: what exactly do you want to solve?

Comment: You have hardcod dimension. you have to make different dimen.xml for different resolution.

Comment: 9 patch drawables for different resolutions and also give a thought to @Dheerubhai Bansal's answer as well.

Comment: @pskink: i face issue in round shape in small resolution device so i want to solve this issue

Comment: @Dheerubhai Bansal: i already try this one but i still getting same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
I think your XML code is right, but you need to change your `home_gray_bg_left_corner`.

Try this drawable:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="@dimen/spacing_5dp"
            android:left="@dimen/spacing_5dp"
            android:right="@dimen/spacing_5dp"
            android:top="@dimen/spacing_5dp" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/spacing_30dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2px"
            android:color="@color/color_gray" />
    </shape>
```